# textarea onChange not updating the state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**onChange** method is not working as it work with **input tags**. When I print the value on change of textarea it shows an Object.

```
Class Main extends Component{
    state={ value:'' }
    handleChange=(value)=>{
         this.setState({value})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <textarea onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} row="3" />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245017/react-modifying-textarea-values ,is this helps?

Comment: yes got it..thank you

Answer (score 0):

`onChange={}` returns an event object, not the value.

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```

This case is described in React's documentation:

```
class EssayForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 'Please write an essay about your favorite DOM element.'
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('An essay was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Essay:
          <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

the state needs to be inside the constructor

```js
class Main extends Component{
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
     this.state={ value:'' }
   }
   handleChange=(event)=>{
      this.setState({event.traget.value})
   }

    render(){

        return(
            <textarea onChange={this.handleChange.bind)} value={this.state.value} row="3" />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set an initial value of state outside of the constructor with `state =`. In a constructor, you have to use "this." as a prefix `this.state =`.