# React - Set TextArea value as HTML

Tags: reactjs

I have one  inside react functional component, and would like to set the value of textarea as html.I try to set the value using useState hook.

Exactly asking, what is the equivalent for **document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML** in React using useState hook?

Comment: check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245017/react-modifying-textarea-values/33245539

Answer (score 1):

in React, state changes automatically re-renders the DOM so you dont need `document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML`.

What you can do is, write your state inside JSX tags like this:

```
<p>{this.state.text}</p>
```

When your state changes, the DOM will automatically re-render and your text will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

If the textarea is inside your react component, you can render it with `useState`.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  
  // render textarea with new props when value changes
  return <textarea id='foo'>{value}<textarea>
}
```

If the textarea is outside your react component, you could use `useState` and `useEffect`.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // run this command when value changes
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = value
  }, [value])
  
  return <div /> // or anything you want
}
```